# Hung shell script when called from python

Tags: python, linux, shell

python pythontop.py # Hangs in test.sh. cat of urandom is not truncated at all

pythontop.py

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['test.sh'])
```

test.sh

```
RAND=`cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9'| fold -w 10 |  head -n 1`
```

EDIT:Folks apologies for any confusion. It turns out simply calling the shell script from python itself causes the script to hang.
UPDATE:
More update. If I insert a tee before head. I get a broken pipe message. Which means head did its job. Got a line and closed the file. 
`cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9'| fold -w 10 | tee | head -n 1` 
 I see the script still hung even after the broken pipe message! 
UPDATE:
Folks, I find this easily recreatable in linuxcontainers.org machine. I did this so that those reading this question can confirm this observation with their own experiments. Since this seems a little too hard to be true.
https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/try-it/

Comment: why do you want to call `perl` from `python` which in turn calls a `sh` script?

Comment: works for me...pythontop.py does not hang (using python 2.7 and perl 5.24)

Comment: Thanks for responding.
Let me check the versions..

Comment: Stuck with a large perl codebase which I cannot modify. Was writing a quick python code to check some stuff.. in an automated way.

Now, can someone tell me what a downvote on a question means? Downvoting a question seems absurd unless it is redundant and answered all over the internet. I can always change the way I generate the random file name but I got curious and I came here for possible reasons.

Comment: I have now removed the perl step in teh middle.. still hangs for me.. but as xxfelixxx pointed that he sees no issue.. let me try his versions

Comment: even with python 2.7, I still see the issue.

Comment: More update. If I insert a tee before head. I get a broken pipe message. Which means head did its job. Got a line and closed the file. <br>
`cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9'| fold -w 10 | tee | head -n 1` <br>

I see the script still hung after the broken pipe message!

Comment: You remove any newlines and whitespace so `fold -w` will keep on reading the stream forever. Voting to close as typo/trivial.

Comment: fold -w 10 _inserts_ newline after every 10 characters. fold does not care about newlines in its input. it is head that is supposed to closed the file/pipe after reading first line from fold output.

Comment: @xxfelixxx I finally found a way for you folks to recreate. Go to linuxcontainers.org. write test.sh and subrocess.call the same form python. You will see the hang.

Comment: @user3500383 I can confirm it hangs in your linuxcontainer setup...

Comment: I got it to stop hanging in the LXD container by changing the invocation to: `subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', 'test.sh'], shell=True) `

Answer (score 0):

Although your code works just fine for me on my laptop, it seems to hang in a containerized environment, such as [linux containers](http://linuxcontainers.org).

Changing

```
subprocess.call(['test.sh'])
```

to

```
subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', 'test.sh'], shell=True)
```

stops the script from hanging.

The [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) advises against using `shell=True` on arbitrary unsanitized input from untrusted sources, so you have been warned.